# Properly typing generic object property access

Tags: flowtype

I have a bit of JS that I've removed all of the unimportant bits from, and I'm trying to add Flow types to it:

```js
function doStuff(key, data, callback) {
  callback(data[key]);
}
```

In this case, `data` is a non-disjoint union of about 30 different object types and `callback` is a function that expects exactly one of those types.

My initial thoughts were to type it like this:

```js
function doStuff2<TKey: $Keys<Data>>(key: TKey, data: Data, callback: ($ElementType<Data, TKey>) => void): void {
  callback(data[key]);
}
```

An example of what `Data` might look like:

```js
type Data = {|
  a: {| username: string, password: string |},
  b: {| alert: string |},
  c: {| prompt: string, primaryAction: ActionItem, secondaryAction: ActionItem |},
  d: {| validCountries: Array<Country> |},
  /* and so on... */
|};
```

However, this doesn't work. If the `Data` type is just `{| a: number, b: string |}`, then I get errors that number is incompatible with string and string is incompatible with number.

My questions are:

1. Why doesn't this work? What type is `$ElementType<Data, TKey>` and why is it incompatible with `typeof data[key]`?
2. What can I do to fix this without changing the type of `Data`?